# C Program with Linked Lists Crashing At The End

Tags: c, debugging, linked-list

I'm working on an assignment that is the beginning of a game of Boggle. The basic premise is we have a text file with 96 characters in it, and our program is going to read in those characters separately and add them as nodes in to a linear linked list and then copy each item to another linear linked list that will place 6 characters on each die, which will total to 16 dice. My program is now working properly (thanks in part to feedback I received on here), but it crashes at the end of execution, and I'm not sure why. Would greatly appreciate any guidance, as my compiler is not giving me any errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Struct for data
struct boggleDataNode
{
    char data[3];
    struct boggleDataNode *nextData;
};

// Struct for die
struct boggleDieSideNode
{
    char dieSideData[3];
    struct boggleDieSideNode *nextSide;
};

// Function to read the data file "BoggleData.txt"
void read(struct boggleDataNode **head1)
{
    char ch[3];

    FILE *input;

    input = fopen("BoggleData.txt", "r");

    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open data file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(fscanf(input, "%s", ch) != EOF)
        {
            addBoggleData(head1, ch);
        }
    }

    fclose(input);

    return;
}

// Function to add character from file to BoggleData Linked List
void addBoggleData(struct boggleDataNode **head1, char * ch)
{
    struct boggleDataNode *temp = NULL;
    struct boggleDataNode *right = NULL;

    temp = (struct boggleDataNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDataNode));

    strcpy(temp->data, ch);

    temp->nextData = NULL;

    if (*head1 == NULL)
    {
        *head1 = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        right = *head1;

        while(right->nextData != NULL)
        {
            right = right->nextData;
        }

        right->nextData = temp;
    }

    return;
}

// Function to add a node to the linked list that contains the side data for each die
void addBoggleDieSide(struct boggleDataNode *head1, struct boggleDieSideNode **head2, int index)
{
    int i = 0;

    struct boggleDieSideNode *temp = NULL;
    struct boggleDieSideNode *right = NULL;

    struct boggleDataNode *helper = NULL;

    temp = (struct boggleDieSideNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDieSideNode));

    helper = (struct boggleDataNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDataNode));

    helper = head1;

    for(i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        helper = helper->nextData;
    }

    strcpy(temp->dieSideData, helper->data);

    temp->nextSide = NULL;

    if (*head2 == NULL)
    {
        *head2 = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        right = *head2;

        while(right->nextSide != NULL)
        {
            right = right->nextSide;
        }

        right->nextSide = temp;
    }

    return;
}

// Function to display the nodes of the linked list that contains the data from the data file
void displayDataFile(struct boggleDataNode *head1)
{
    int value = 0;
    struct boggleDataNode *temp = NULL;
    temp = (struct boggleDataNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDataNode));

    temp = head1;

    printf("**** Displaying Boggle Data ****\n");

    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("Data value %d : %s\n", value, temp->data);
            value++;

            temp = temp->nextData;

            if(temp == NULL)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Function to display the nodes of the linked list that contains the data on the six sides of the die
void displayDieSide(struct boggleDieSideNode *head2)
{
    int value = 0;
    struct boggleDieSideNode *temp = NULL;
    temp = (struct boggleDieSideNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDieSideNode));

    temp = head2;

    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("Side %d : %s\n", value, temp->dieSideData);
            value++;

            temp = temp->nextSide;

            if(temp == NULL)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Main function
int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0;

    struct boggleDataNode *head1 = NULL;
    struct boggleDieSideNode *head2 = NULL;

    read(&head1);

    displayDataFile(head1);

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        head2 = NULL;

        for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            addBoggleDieSide(head1, &head2, counter);
            counter++;
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("**** Displaying Die Side Data ****\n");
        displayDieSide(head2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Move `void read(struct boggleDataNode **head1)` below `void addBoggleData(struct boggleDataNode **head1, char * ch)` or add a prototype for `void addBoggleData(struct boggleDataNode **head1, char * ch)` to the beginning of the file. Otherwise, it has no idea what that function is in  `void read(struct boggleDataNode **head1)`

Comment: Just in commenting out some of the code, I believe the error is being produced somehow from the addBoggleDieSide function, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: That will clear the `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘addBoggleData'`

Comment: You are correct David, it did fix that particular warning, thanks for that. But the program still looks to be locking up after completion, although it gets to that point faster now.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a sample input file ?

Comment: Show me `BoggleData.txt` your `fscanf` looks FUBAR (by editing your question and adding a few lines showing the format and content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUgh. You are going to kill yourself when you see the primary mistake.

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    head2 = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        addBoggleDieSide(head1, &head2, counter);
        counter++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("**** Displaying Die Side Data ****\n");
    displayDieSide(head2);
}
```

What is happening to `i` in **both** loops?  Make it look like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    head2 = NULL;

    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        addBoggleDieSide(head1, &head2, counter);
        counter++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("**** Displaying Die Side Data ****\n");
    displayDieSide(head2);
}
```

That is only part of your problem. The rest are improvement you can make. Most importantly **do not cast the result of malloc**. The remainder are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Struct for data
struct boggleDataNode
{
    char data[3];
    struct boggleDataNode *nextData;
};

// Struct for die
struct boggleDieSideNode
{
    char dieSideData[3];
    struct boggleDieSideNode *nextSide;
};

// Function to add character from file to BoggleData Linked List
void addBoggleData(struct boggleDataNode **head1, char * ch)
{
    struct boggleDataNode *temp = NULL;
    struct boggleDataNode *right = NULL;

    temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);

    strcpy(temp->data, ch);

    temp->nextData = NULL;

    if (*head1 == NULL)
    {
        *head1 = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        right = *head1;

        while(right->nextData != NULL)
        {
            right = right->nextData;
        }

        right->nextData = temp;
    }

    return;
}

// Function to read the data file "BoggleData.txt"
void read(struct boggleDataNode **head1)
{
    char ch[3];

    FILE *input;

    input = fopen("BoggleData.txt", "r");

    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open data file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(fscanf(input, "%2[^\n]%*c", ch) != EOF)
        {
            addBoggleData(head1, ch);
        }
    }

    fclose(input);

    return;
}

// Function to add a node to the linked list that contains the side data for each die
void addBoggleDieSide(struct boggleDataNode *head1, struct boggleDieSideNode **head2, int index)
{
    int i = 0;

    struct boggleDieSideNode *temp = NULL;
    struct boggleDieSideNode *right = NULL;

    struct boggleDataNode *helper = NULL;

    temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);

    // helper = malloc(sizeof *helper);

    helper = head1;

    for(i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        helper = helper->nextData;
    }

    strcpy (temp->dieSideData, helper->data);

    temp->nextSide = NULL;

    if (*head2 == NULL)
    {
        *head2 = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        right = *head2;

        while(right->nextSide != NULL)
        {
            right = right->nextSide;
        }

        right->nextSide = temp;
    }

    return;
}

// Function to display the nodes of the linked list that contains the data from the data file
void displayDataFile(struct boggleDataNode *head1)
{
    int value = 0;
    struct boggleDataNode *temp = NULL;
    // temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);

    temp = head1;

    printf("**** Displaying Boggle Data ****\n");

    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("Data value %d : %s\n", value, temp->data);
            value++;

            temp = temp->nextData;
/*
            if(temp == NULL)
            {
                break;
            }*/
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Function to display the nodes of the linked list that contains the data on the six sides of the die
void displayDieSide(struct boggleDieSideNode *head2)
{
    int value = 0;
    struct boggleDieSideNode *temp = NULL;
    // temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);

    temp = head2;

    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("Side %d : %s\n", value, temp->dieSideData);
            value++;

            temp = temp->nextSide;

//             if(temp == NULL)
//             {
//                 break;
//             }
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Main function
int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    struct boggleDataNode *head1 = NULL;
    struct boggleDieSideNode *head2 = NULL;

    read(&head1);

    displayDataFile(head1);

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        head2 = NULL;

        for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            addBoggleDieSide(head1, &head2, counter);
            counter++;
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("**** Displaying Die Side Data ****\n");
        displayDieSide(head2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/lldicecrash
**** Displaying Boggle Data ****
Data value 0 : 1
Data value 1 : 5
Data value 2 : 4
Data value 3 : 2
Data value 4 : 1
Data value 5 : 6
Data value 6 : 2
<snip>
Data value 94 : 2
Data value 95 : 5

**** Displaying Die Side Data ****
Side 0 : 1
Side 1 : 5
Side 2 : 4
Side 3 : 2
Side 4 : 1
Side 5 : 6

**** Displaying Die Side Data ****
Side 0 : 2
Side 1 : 1
Side 2 : 2
Side 3 : 5
Side 4 : 3
Side 5 : 5

<snip 13 more die>

**** Displaying Die Side Data ****
Side 0 : 5
Side 1 : 3
Side 2 : 4
Side 3 : 5
Side 4 : 2
Side 5 : 5
```

**Note:** you really should be reading `ch` as a character and not a string (and handling it as a character in the structs and throughout your code). That would simplify things a bit. However, that is up to you. (it might be required for the assignment) To read as a string, you should improve your `fscanf` conversion specifier. Look at the changes I made.

**Also Note:** I have no idea what your actual data values are. I simply created a workable data file with:

```
$ for i in {1..96}; do echo $((RANDOM % 6 + 1)) >> BoggleData.txt; done
```

Comment: Updated. Thanks. Protects against stray chars in the data.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was such a simple mistake on the for loops. Embarrassed I didn't catch that, it did resolve the issue, thank you again David. I'll be looking through your changes and see if I have any other questions. As far as the ch being a string and not a character, some of the lines of data being read in are more than 1 character, so I had to choose a string. But I appreciate the callout on the fscanf, thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help. I've done that to myself more times that I can count. Don't worry, this won't be the last time you do it. As for the rest of your code, most of the changes were just commenting out unnecessary `malloc` calls where you are just using the pointer and have no need to allocate a struct behind it. (the only time you need to allocate space is if you are copying data to a **new** node, otherwise, you can reference the values with a simple pointer)